# bash scripting copying all files in folder

Tags: bash

I'm writing a shell script as follows:

```sh
for file in `ls`
do
  mkdir "$file"_folder
  cp $file "$file"_folder
done
```

What I want to do is to make a folder for each file in the current directory with its name and then underscore folder as the name and then copy that file into it. My problem is that the file names contain spaces in them. How do I escape them? 
There are many resources explaining how to do this for variables but none of them can be applied to this situation where I use a for loop to get the names.

Comment: The problem is that you use the output of `ls` to drive the loop. Your quoting inside the loop is perfect.

Comment: Oops, not entirely perfect after all; as noted in one of the replies, you should double-quote all variable interpolations (at least until you know under what circumstances it's okay not to quote).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `ls` there, use shell globbing. (In general, [do not parse the output of  `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).)

```
for file in *
do
  # only consider files, not directories
  if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    new_dir="$file"_folder
    # create the directory
    if [ ! -d "$new_dir" ] ; then
      mkdir "$new_dir"
      if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
        # handle directory creation eror
      fi
    fi
    # possibly check for the copied file existence here
    # and deal with that appropriately (i.e. skip/error/copy anyway)
    cp "$file" "$new_dir"
  fi
done
```

Comment: You forgot the quotes around the first `$file` in the `cp` command.

Comment: You didn't have to add `nullglob` to your earlier solution; if `file` is set to `'*'`, `[ -f "${file}" ]` evaluates to false anyway skipping over a possibly non-existent file named `*`.

Comment: @Adrian: does it do any harm though? Isn't it relatively good practice if a no-match can be expected?

Comment: It's a matter of preference, but consider that 1) it introduces a bashism to an otherwise possibly "portable" script and 2) you need to remember unsetting it after the code part in question as it might introduce non-expected behavior (see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob) why it is not a good idea to use it on a "set as default and forget"-basis) for later parts of your script. This is why I myself prefer to just add the simple `[ -f|-d|-e "${foo}" ]` check inside a loop - it's easy to read, less characters to type, you don't need to think and it is more portable. It *can* do harm.

Comment: @Adrian: Hadn't thought about the possible side-effects that much. Thanks for all that information, much appreciated.

Comment: @Mat Also see it like this: in a case like here where you want to iterate over specific kinds of files only (files OR directories OR ...) you need to have the test there anyway, and every superfluous code line unnecessarily increases the maintenance overhead. But as I said, if you know what you are doing and there is no necessity for portability because you use bashism all over the place anyway there is nothing wrong with it :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
find . -type f -exec mkdir {}_folder \; -exec cp {} {}_folder \;
```

It finds all regular files in the current directory, creates the folder (first `-exec`), and copies the file into the new folder (second `-exec`).

Answer (score 0):

You [do not parse](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
`ls` for exactly this reason

```sh
for file in *
do
  mkdir "${file}_folder"
  cp "$file" "${file}_folder"
done
```

Comment: Without `nullglob`, this will fail if there are no files in the directory (`file` will be set to the literal `*`), hence the `[ -f "${file}" ]` check in Mat's answer.